# Spring Security catch RuntimeException

Tags: spring, spring-security, nullpointerexception, runtimeexception

i've extended UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, which contains method: 
successfulAuthentication-Method.

I've override this Method. During of exectuion of overriden successfulAuthentication-method i get NullPointerException.

```
@Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {            
        customAuthenticationPlugin.execute(userInfo, (AuthenticatedAuthenticationToken) authResult);
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
    }
```

How can i define, that on any Exceptions while security-process, it should be redirected to some error-page?

UPDATE:

I've already tried on NullPointerException redirect  to special ErrorServlet (ErrorServlet extends HttpServlet)
within my web.xml, but it does not work. Probably due to spring-security

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: What servlet container do you use? You can map all errors in your configuration.

Comment: thx. for replay.
Server Version: jetty/8.1.16.v20140903
Servlet Version: 3.0 JSP Version: 2.1

Could you send me example, how could i map this ? On which configuration should it be done, spring-security-config or on web.xml ?